# ArrayList and JOptionPane.showInputDialog()

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to learn Java and have come a long way from PHP, I tried to apply the same mentality when creating my code. But as many of you have already known, it doesn't work that easily.

So with that said, I have a question. I want to create a drop down list from items in an `ArrayList`. I am fond of the idea of using the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` method to attempt this.

This is what I have currently, but I get an error telling me that `no suitable method found for showInputDialog`

```
ArrayList<String> projectList = new ArrayList<String>();

while(results.next())
    projectList.add(results.getString("project"));

String inputDialog = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Choose project to open", "Open Project", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, projectList, "--");
```

I know that the issue is that when I pass the `ArrayList` as the array object I get thrown this error. But if I did something like

```
Object[] projectList = {"one", "two"};
```

then it works as intended, I then tried to maybe do this and pass in `projects` as my array object.

```
Object[] projects = {projectList.toString()};
```

This somewhat works, but then the output looked like `"one, two"` in drop down list as 1 line item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `ArrayList` to `Object[]` if needed using [List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29), ie:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
Object[] result = list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

projectList is an ArrayList, convert it to array and then pass it to the method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(). Please check List.toArray() method.

```
String [] projects = projectList.toArray(new String[projectList.size()]);
```

Comment: wow, yes. This worked, so ArrayList isn't seen as an actual array object in Java?

Comment: Array and ArrayList are different.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
    Object[] projectListArray =new Object[projectList.size()];
    projectList.toArray(projectListArray);

String inputDialog = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Choose project to open", "Open Project", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, projectListArray , "--");
```

Hope it helps.